# Пустое значение ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Имею такой код, который вызывается после изменения `ComboBox`:

```
private void ComboBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
    TextBlock tx = (TextBlock)cb.SelectedItem;
    string shir = tx.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Shir1 = shir;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    MessageBox.Show(shir);
}
```

Переменная `shir` выходит пустой

Вот мой XAML код:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selected" SelectedIndex="0" Style="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" Height="23" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}">
    <TextBlock><Run Text="800x600"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="1024x780"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="1280x768"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="1440x900"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="1536x1024"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="1600x900"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="1920x1080"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="2048x1080"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="2560x1600"/></TextBlock>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Хватит использовать WPF так криво... Ну серьезно, WPF это привязки, стили, XAML, а вы над ним так издеваетесь.

Comment: :( Что в коде-то не так?

Comment: Хм, наверно... Все? У вас должно быть `<ComboBox ItemsSource = "{Binding SomeCollection}" SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectItem}" />` и соответственно два свойства, а сейчас вы попросту используете UI как некое место хранения ваших данных, да еще и генерите походу интерфейс кодом, а это ооооочень бредово.

Comment: дополнил xaml код

Comment: И это что-то должно изменить в моем комментарии? Я вам сказал, что вы используете UI как БАЗУ, некоторое место, где хранятся ваши данные, что очень, очень плохо. Вот представьте, что вам эти размеры нужны будут в другом классе, другом окне, да даже может в другом проекте, как доставать будете? Будете искать открытое окно, искать в нем нужный контрол и уже в нем брать эти размеры? Не кажется это странным..? Короче, не используете UI как источник данных, он должен лишь отображать информацию, а не хранить ее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если решать именно поставленную вами задачу и отвечать на вопрос "почему пустое значение", то все дело в том, что вы непойми зачем используете внутри `<TextBlock>` еще и `<Run>`, вот теперь подумайте, у вас есть такая иерархия:

```
<TextBlock Text = "">
    <Run Text = "800x600" />
</TextBlock>
```

Что выдаст вам данный код?

```
TextBlock tx = (TextBlock)cb.SelectedItem;
string shir = tx.Text;
```

Думаю, свою проблему вы поняли. Давайте теперь решать. У вас есть два выхода:

1. Отказаться от `<Run>` (он у вас действительно лишний).
2. Взять текст из него. Делается это примерно так:

   ```
   var inline = tx.Inlines.FirstInline;
   var shir = new TextRange(inline.ContentStart, inline.ContentEnd).Text;
   ```

---

Но повторю еще раз: то, как вы разрабатываете WPF проект, это просто ужаснейший подход, ибо вы сами себе делаете грабли подобными действиями. Уберите из проекта все `x:Name` (кроме стилей) и пробуйте разрабатывать его так. Представьте, что у вас простой консольный проект, где вы оперируете только классами, а не интерфейсом, вот разработайте сначала эти слои, а уж затем думайте, как к этому всему прикрутить UI и не поверите, при помощи привязок и прочих инструментов WPF, UI можно (и нужно) полностью отделять от логики (читаем про MVVM)! Так что мой вам совет, забудьте про то, что вы сейчас делайте и начните учить привязки (примеров полно, даже вон вам ответ дали).